`sonarqube-scanner@^4.0.0` doesn’t return non-zero exit code in case of Quality Gate failure

SonarQube: Developer Edition v10.5.1 (90531)
sonarqube-scanner version: 4.0.0 or 4.0.1
Used npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sonarqube-scanner
Node.js 20.14

When we run it as
npx sonarqube-scanner@^4.0.0 -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait="true" [....]

we expect non-zero exit code if Quality Gateway finds new issues that must be fixed.
But the actual result: this command always return 0 exit code, and our build never fails.
At the same time, sonarqube-scanner@^3.5.0 works as expected and really fails the build, but ^4.0.0 doesn't.
Does anyone know how to set it up with sonarqube-scanner@^4.0.0 and Node.js 20+?


It is a bug, confirmed buy sonarqube-scanner developers.
See https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-scanner-4-0-0-doesnt-return-non-zero-exit-code-in-case-of-quality-gate-failure/118755/4
And Jira issue: https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/SCANNPM-39
